# String with comma separated pixel values (int8) to UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, uiimageview, pixel

I am doing a small task where I receive a text string (json message) via TCP/IP, and one entry contains one long list of pixel values for a grayscale image, so the values are in the range of 0-255 e.g.

```
NSString *foo = @"0,0,0,1,1,1,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,1,1,1,1,100,100,100,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1";
```

This string I would like to display in an UIImageView on my iOS device. I know the width and height of the image (part of the json message), so for example the above could be an image with width = 6 and height = 5, which match foo with 30 entries (pixel values).

I tried iterating through the string with a for loop and NSRange for each line in the image (where NSRange is 0,5 for the first line, 6-11 for the next, and so on), but I cannot figure out if this is the correct way to go, and what data format I should transform it into e.g. NSData, NSArray or something else to be able to use it for UIImageView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
NSString *foo = @"0,0,0,1,1,1,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,1,1,1,1,100,100,100,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1";
NSArray *colors = [foo componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
int width = 6;
int height = 5;

//create drawing context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(width, height), NO, 0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//draw pixels
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        int index = x + y*width;
        CGFloat val = [[colors objectAtIndex:index] floatValue];
        val = val / 255.0f;
        CGFloat components[4] = {val, val, val, 1.0f};
        CGContextSetFillColor(context, components);
        CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(x, y, 1.0f, 1.0f));
    }
}

//capture resultant image
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGRect frame = self.imageView.frame;
frame.size = CGSizeMake(width, height);
self.imageView.frame = frame;

self.imageView.image = image;
```

Comment: It does seem to work, however, two issues: 1) the image is mirrored and 2) the lower numbered colors are transparent and not black, so it goes from transparent (0) --> white (255).

Comment: I figured out the coloring, I used e.g. CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor); to fill value 100 with black and so forth. Now I just need to get the image corrected. I looks like it is mirrored along the horizontal axis.

Comment: Also from a performance point of view, this is really slow when you start using bigger images e.g. 2048×1536. Is there a better way to achieve the same without the for loops, I reckon having inner loops makes the process much slower?

Comment: @Simon Bøgh, maybe it's better to change your service to return a Base64 string. 
So I did in my app.

`NSString *base64Str = [dict objectForKey:@"_photo"];
NSData *base64Data = [NSData dataWithBase64String:base64Str];
UIImage *photo = [UIImage imageWithData:base64Data];`

Comment: unfortunately I cannot change the output of the service. To correct the image I ended up adding `height-y` to `CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(x, height-y, 1.0f, 1.0f));` and now it works. Thank you for the answer!